# Scrapy item result inside an html code

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

it is possible to insert into html code the result of a scraped item? How can I implement it?

Something like this:

```
for ntp in response.css('div.content-1col-nobox'):
description = ntp.xpath('normalize-space(//div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/div/blockquote[2]/p/text())').extract_first()
'Description': '<html><body>......'description'..............</body></html>',\
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible, to do so I suggest you document yourself on Regular Expressions and how they can help you place the description string at the desired place of your html code

Comment: Thank you @ClementLombard I would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple string manipulation .
1. `'%d' % (description)`

2. `'<html>{}  some more html </html>'.format(description)`

you will need to have your description variable in string format .
str(description) will work i guess.

```
description = ntp.xpath('normalize-space(//div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/div/blockquote[2]/p/text())').extract_first()

'Description': '<html><body>...... {} ..............</body></html>'.format(str(descripion))
```

as suggested in comment you can use python RE https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Thank you @AshishRp It worked fine, just as I spectated. Thank you again